# Creating a PHP log without database

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress plugin which logs bruteforce attacks, but this is my second plugin ever and I'm unsure how to do this.

I grab the IP of the machine who is bruteforce attacking the `wp-admin` form by using `guard_get_ip_address()`.

**But now I'm stuck on how to save the actual IP at the moment of when the user is bruteforce attacking. Is there any way to save this to a table like I created below?**

```
function logs() {
    ?>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>IP</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo guard_get_ip_address(); ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
function add_logs() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget('dashboard_widget', 'Logs', 'logs');
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'add_logs' );
```

---

Edit: the function `guard_get_ip_address()` only attempts to grab IPs;

```
function guard_get_ip_address() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: why save html? html is a massive waste of space. if you want to log stuff, then write out JUSt the information you want to save, and format it for display when needed. `file_put_contents('log.txt', $ip_addr, FILE_APPEND)`

Comment: @MarcB Are you sure WordPress doesn't have a function for that stuff? I want to fully use the functions WordPress has to offer for this one :)

Comment: probably does, but I try to avoid learning as little about wordpuke's (not a typo) guts as possible.

Comment: Why not just scrape the acess logs

Comment: @Dagon Can you explain that a little more?

Answer (score 0):

// LOG DATA WILL STORE IN FOLDER WITH YOURFILENAME.DOC USE TO PRINT THIS CODE , CALL THIS FUNCTION WITH ANCHOR TAG FROM YOUR VIEW PAGE

```
                   public function file_log()
          {                
         $id = YOURFILENAME; 
           $file = APPPATH.'yourfile/'.$id.'.doc';
           $content = file_get_contents($file);
           echo '<html><body style="background-color:white; padding- 
              left:20px; padding-top:40px;">'.$content.'</body></html>';
               }
```

// create Base.php file

```
     function get_file_force_contents($contents,$LogfileName,$logUserName){

     if($contents){

        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
        $logtime =  Date('d-M-Y h:i A');
        $dir = APPPATH.'yourfile/';
        @$file = $dir.'/'.$LogfileName.'.doc';
        if(!is_dir($dir)) mkdir($dir, 0777, TRUE);
        @$current = file_get_contents(@$file);
        $current .= '<br>'.$logtime.' - '.'<strong>'.$logUserName.'</strong> - '.$contents;
        file_put_contents($file, $current);
        }
}
```

// controller

```
  require_once(APPPATH.'/Base.php');


   function log{

    $logUserName = 'logged in UserName';
    $LogfileName = YourFILEName;
    $LogData = json_decode($this->input->post('something1'), true);
    $LogArray = array();
    if(is_array($LogData)){
        foreach($LogData as $key => $log){
            foreach($log as $key1 =>$v){
                $LogArray[$key1] = $v;
            }
        }
        $array = array_unique($LogArray, SORT_REGULAR);
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $output = $value."<br>"; 
            $contents = $output;
            //print_r($contents);    
            get_file_force_contents($contents,$LogfileName,$logUserName);
        }
    }
   }
```

// your jquery code
// for input change start

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var arr = [];
   var InputPrevVal;
   var InputCurrentVal;
  $("input").on("focus",function () {

}).change(function() {
    var InputID = $(this).attr('id');
    var InputPrevVal = $('#'+InputID).attr('value');
    var InputCurrentVal = $(this).val();

    if(InputID == 'refrence_name'){
        var ValueChangesForInput = 'Enquiry Person: ';
        var value = $('#something').html('Updated '+ValueChangesForInput+' '+InputPrevVal+' To '+InputCurrentVal);
        arr.push({Reference_Name:$('#something').val()});
    }

    $('#something1').val(JSON.stringify(arr));
    //console.log('Input Changes : '+InputPrevVal+' To '+InputCurrentVal);
});
```

// for dropdown

```
   var PreviousValue;
   var SelectedIdChng;

   $("select").on("focus",function () {

  var SelectedId = $(this).attr("id");
  var PreviousValue = $(this).attr("attr");

}).change(function() {

    var SelectedIdChng = $(this).attr("id");
    var CurrentValue = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    var PreviousValue = $(this).attr("attr");

    if(SelectedIdChng == 'destination'){
        var ValueChangesFor = 'Destination: ';
        var value = $('#something').html('Updated '+ValueChangesFor+' 
    '+PreviousValue+' To '+CurrentValue);
        arr.push({Destination:$('#something').val()});
    }


        console.log(arr);
        $('#something1').val(JSON.stringify(arr));


     });
  </script>
```

// VIEW PAGE

```
                     <textarea id="something" name="something" class="" style="width: 
                   1300px; height: 100px;"> 
                     </textarea>
                       <textarea id="something1" name="something1" class="" 
               style="width: 1300px; height: 100px;"></textarea>
            <select name="destination" id="destination" required="" attr="At your 
              works/Door Delivery">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1" selected="">At your works/Door Delivery</option>
            <option value="2">At our works</option>
            <option value="3">Godown Delivery</option>
            </select>

            <input type="text" class="form-control valid" name="refrence_name" 
             id="refrence_name" placeholder="refrence_name" value="Sonu Vishwakarma">
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

in your plugin, you will need to save the server data into a javascript element, in which you can use JQUERY to execute.

The fastest way I know in my head at the moment is Cookies.

1. Create a cookie in PHP and pull it in JS:

   $cookie_name = "IP";
   $cookie_value = "127.0.0.1";  //add your value here
   setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
2. var x = document.cookie;

from there, you can use JQUERY to add to the table:

$('tableid tr:first td').html(x);

Comment: How can I retrieve the data stored in there to the table like in my post?